# PHP having an issue inserting a ip2long into my database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ip

So I'm uploading my website to my webserver that I just bought, everything worked perfectly on my computer. But now I'm having a problem when inserting data in my database, I tracked down the problem to the IP addess of the user creating the row which is inserted in every row inserted.

I have a php function that returns the `ip2long` value and it looks like this :

```
function ip2()
    {
        return ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    }
```

Then to insert it into my database the sql code looks like this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Users` 
                    (
                        `Username`,
                        `Password`,
                        `Email`,
                        `ip_created`
                    )
                    VALUES 
                    (
                        '".$db->sql_escape(htmlspecialchars($this->username, ENT_QUOTES))."',
                        '".$db->sql_escape($this->secure_pass)."',
                        '".$db->sql_escape($this->clean_email)."',
                        '".ip2()."'
                    )";

$db->sql_query($sql))
```

The `ip_created` field is an `int` of length 10

All of the database interaction is handled in a php class, maybe this could be an issue.

I really have no idea where the problem can come from and it is really starting to bother my. Everything worked perfectly on my localhost version.

Comment: `ip2long()` may return a negative number on a 32-bit system. If your database field is `INT UNSIGNED` this will not play the game correctly. I personally prefer to `pack('N')` the IP address and store it as a `VARBINARY(4)`, YMMV

Answer (score 3):

[id2long man page comments contain:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php)

> Be aware when you're running 64bit system, ip2long will result 64 bit
>   integer which doesn't fit in MySQL INT, you can use BIGINT or INT
>   UNSIGNED because on 64bit systems ip2long will never return negative
>   integer. See also https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54338

Could that be the cause?

Comment: This seems like an odd problem. Even though 64-bit systems will store the return value of `ip2long()` in a 64-bit integer, when it is cast to a string (for use in a query) this will not be reflected. As long as the MySQL data type is large enough to store the data, the integer type being used by PHP *should* be irrelevant.

Comment: I fixed this problem using ``printf("%u", ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));`` to always get a positive value and also used ``bigint`` instead of ``int``. But there are still some stuff not working, when inserting rows with random numbers generated for example. Do I need to change all the ``int`` fields to ``bigint`` in order for it to work ?